# Why does the Flattr popup covers the button in firefox?

Tags: firefox, flattr

I have manually implemented the [Flattr](http://flattr.com/) button to my site.

In Firefox (Windows) the "popout" covers the button so one can't press it.

Any other browser renders the popout in the correct place. Can someone confirm this? Or is it a conflict on my site?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't mention which site is yours I'm left to speculate on the reasons for this and if I do then I think it is that your body-element doesn't start at the top left of your browser and that therefor positioning of the popout fails due to browsers inability to correctly account for offset body elements.

We've had reports of people experiencing this problem in eg. WordPress where the admin-bar that's showed when a user is logged in pushes the entire site down 20 pixels or something and makes the position of the popout be of by 20 pixels. Could it be something similar for you - that you're logged in in Firefox and not in other browsers?

As far as I know there's no workaround for this limitation - eg. jQuery [can't account for it](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) either.

Good thing though: If your layout has a body with an offset or something else that makes the popout not work for you you can disable it by setting popout 0 in the [settings of the button](http://developers.flattr.net/button/).